# How can I get rid of this invisible file?

Tags: linux, files, unicode, zfs

### Background

I have a folder named `akorg✽`. That Unicode character causes headaches for me when software makes incorrect assumptions about the text encoding of my file paths, so I'd like to remove it from the name.

### The problem

You'd think this would be easy:

```
$ mv akorg✽ akorg
mv: cannot move ‘akorg✽’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘akorg/akorg✽’
```

but—that's strange—it thinks a folder called `akorg` already exists. I'm pretty sure there isn't one:

```
$ ls -la
total 699K
drwxr-xr-x 15 ak ak   15 Jun 12 17:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 57 ak ak 4.0K Jun 12 17:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x 11 ak ak   21 Jun 12 16:58 akorg✽
drwxr-xr-x  2 ak ak    2 May 28 20:47 Desktop
...
```

Still, `stat` says otherwise:

```
$ stat akorg
  File: ‘akorg’
  Size: 21          Blocks: 33         IO Block: 1536   directory
Device: 15h/21d Inode: 292128      Links: 11
...
```

So apparently there is an invisible folder in the way. Whatever, I'll just remove it:

```
$ rmdir akorg
rmdir: failed to remove ‘akorg’: No such file or directory
```

Right, then. What in the world is this thing?

### What I know so far

- I'm using the [stable release](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable) of [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/). Here's the [zpool status and zfs properties](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5759985/).
- `stat` returns the same inode for both `akorg` and `akorg✽`. Searching by that inode returns only `akorg✽`:

  ```
  $ find . -maxdepth 1 -inum 292128
  ./akorg✽
  ```
- More things that don't work on the "invisible" folder:

  ```
  $ rm akorg
  rm: cannot remove ‘akorg’: Is a directory
  $ unlink akorg
  unlink: cannot unlink ‘akorg’: Is a directory
  $ mv akorg akorg_temp
  mv: cannot move ‘akorg’ to ‘akorg_temp’: No such file or directory
  ```
- I get the same results in both Bash 4.2.45 and zsh 5.0.0. In both, tab-completion of `ak` returns only `akorg✽/`.
- The [strace](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5762504/) of my initial renaming attempt confirms that I'm typing the names correctly and that the attempt is thwarted by the preexistence of a folder named `akorg`.
- This response to a more explicit renaming attempt is puzzling and scary:

  ```
  $ mv --verbose --no-target-directory --no-clobber akorg✽ akorg
  removed ‘akorg✽’
  ```

  I don't understand why it claims to have removed `akorg✽`, or why it would try. Fortunately, `ls` and `stat akorg akorg✽` reveal that nothing is actually gone. Here's the [strace](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5762743/).
- To rule out encoding quirks as the cause of this, I've temporarily given `akorg✽` an intermediate name:

  ```
  $ mv --verbose --no-target-directory --no-clobber akorg✽ bananas
  ‘akorg✽’ -> ‘bananas’
  ```

  That worked as expected,

  ```
  $ ls -la
  total 715K
  drwxr-xr-x 16 ak ak   16 Jun 13 15:11 .
  drwxr-xr-x 57 ak ak 4.0K Jun 13 14:03 ..
  drwxr-xr-x 11 ak ak   21 Jun 12 16:58 bananas
  drwxr-xr-x  2 ak ak    2 May 28 20:47 Desktop
  ...
  ```

  but the "invisible" folder is still present:

  ```
  $ stat bananas akorg
    File: ‘bananas’
    Size: 21          Blocks: 33         IO Block: 1536   directory
  Device: 15h/21d Inode: 292128      Links: 11
  ...
    File: ‘akorg’
    Size: 21          Blocks: 33         IO Block: 1536   directory
  Device: 15h/21d Inode: 292128      Links: 11
  ...
  ```

  and `mv` still behaves strangely when I try to use the name `akorg`:

  ```
  $ mv --verbose --no-target-directory --no-clobber bananas akorg
  removed ‘bananas’
  ```

Comment: Does `strace` of `mv` give something like: `execve("/bin/mv", ["mv", "akorg\342\234\275", "akorg"] ...` on first line? Which shell are you using?

Comment: @Sukminder Good thought. It does, and I've updated the question to include the full trace. I'm using Bash and zsh.

Comment: Well, after a reboot and some probing with `zdb -d`, the problem has mysteriously resolved itself. I'm torn between feeling glad that it's resolved and upset that I'll never learn what happened. Should this question be closed, or might it be useful to others in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is weird. *(And this "answer" started as a comment ;), became a bit long for it.)*

Looking at the `strace` it looks like there are no hidden characters or the like, else I suspect you would have seen it in e.g. (which should have resulted in `-1 ENOENT` and not `0` if everything was OK):

```
stat("akorg", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=21, ...}) = 0
```

as you do in:

```
lstat("akorg\342\234\275", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=21, ...}) = 0
```

Came across a mail exchange where one person has the [opposite problem](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2011-November/235148.html). `ls` list the files, but `stat` give `ENOENT` – though that was on FreeBSD.

I do not know much about `zfs`, but could it be that some sync, snapshot or the like has failed and left a corrupted file table? Did you create/have a directory named `akorg` that you deleted before you tried the `mv`?

Do not know if you can get some error descriptions by:

```
# zpool status -v
```

---

One thing to try is check the reverse inode lookup (optionally add yet another `d`) and check `path`:

```
# zdb -dddd <pool-name> <inode>
```

On a folder named `baz`:

```
# zdb -dddd qqq 31
Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
    31    1    16K    512     1K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                    264   bonus  ZFS znode
dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED 
dnode maxblkid: 0
path    /baz
uid     1000
gid     1000
atime   Fri Jun 14 12:39:46 2013
mtime   Fri Jun 14 11:55:33 2013
ctime   Fri Jun 14 11:55:33 2013
crtime  Fri Jun 14 11:55:33 2013
gen 1510
mode    40775
size    2
parent  3
links   2
xattr   0
rdev    0x0000000000000000
microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries
```

On a directory named `foo` holding several subdirectories including one named `akorg✽`:

```
Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
    16    1    16K    512     1K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                    264   bonus  ZFS znode
dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED 
dnode maxblkid: 0
path    /foo
uid     1000
gid     1000
atime   Fri Jun 14 13:10:38 2013
mtime   Fri Jun 14 12:13:18 2013
ctime   Fri Jun 14 12:13:18 2013
crtime  Fri Jun 14 11:41:53 2013
gen 1482
mode    40775
size    6
parent  3
links   6
xattr   0
rdev    0x0000000000000000
microzap: 512 bytes, 4 entries

    foo1 = 15 (type: Directory)
    foo2 = 18 (type: Directory)
    foo = 19 (type: Directory)
    akorg✽ = 30 (type: Directory)
```

---

The settings you have on `zfs get all storage/home-ak-annex` for various name mod also looks sane (as far as I can tell) as well as the other properties by reading [ZFS Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/817-2271/6mhupg6ma/index.html#gcfgr):

```
storage/home-ak-annex  utf8only              off                    -
storage/home-ak-annex  normalization         none                   -
storage/home-ak-annex  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
```

---

If you build `zfs` yourself you can enable debug by `./configure --enable-debug` and play with the above including `-vvvv`, `-bbbb` etc.

Lastly you could open a [new Issue](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues) on the git.

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted since I think it's the right way of approaching the issue and might help others in the future. Somewhat disappointingly, my own case has mysteriously resolved itself so I'm unable to take this any further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: “Has mysteriously resolved itself”… That's not a good sign. Your filesystem may be corrupted in some way, though it's odd as the file name is only stored once. It could be a bug in the filesystem driver. It could also be due to bad RAM — I recommend running a memory test.

Answer (score 5):

As you're using zsh, I recommend tab completion or shell globbing (always echo/ls before removing). If those doesn't work, you have a few options:

Check your filename through a hex dump and use `$'...'` to input it

```
% touch akorg✽   
% ls | grep akorg | hexdump -C
00000000  61 6b 6f 72 67 e2 9c bd  0a                       |akorg....|
00000009
% ls $'akorg\xe2\x9c\xbd'  
akorg✽
% rm $'akorg\xe2\x9c\xbd'
% ls
%
```

Note that the final `0a` above is the newline at the end of the input, so we don't want it in our name.

Use `ls -i` to get the inode number and use `find` to delete it

```
% touch akorg✽
% ls -i
6128574 akorg✽
% find . -inum 6128574
akorg✽
% find . -inum 6128574 -delete
% ls
%
```

You could also `find` it by name (either way, print first!)

Use `ls -b` to get the escaped name and enter it with `$'...'` (This works with nonprinting characters but doesn't seem to affect your unicode one, so this is for others' reference).

```
% ls
foo?bar
% ls -b         
foo\rbar
% rm foo$'\r'bar
% ls
%
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I suppose I didn't make it clear enough earlier, but I'm not actually trying to remove `akorg✽`, just the "invisible" file that's in the way of renaming it.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming `akorg✽` first and seeing if it's just an artifact of the unicode name. Otherwise, it looks like you have the inode number of the ghost from `stat`. Use that: `find . -inum 292128 -exec mv {} foo`

Comment: I've updated my question with the results from your suggestion. Renaming didn't resolve the issue, and finding by inode doesn't return the ghost.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you don't have an invisible directory, but rather that `stat` misprints the unicode characters so that the file name *looks like* `akorg` when on-screen.

Two possible solutions:

1. Use a shell with tab completion (zsh or bash).  At the prompt do: `rm -rf akorg<tab>`.  Zsh at least will complete the file name, escaping shell-special characters as necessary.
2. A one liner, a bit risky: `rm -rf akorg?`

You could do #2 by hand, something like: `ls -1 > filenames`. Use some text editor on the file named "filenames" to delete all lines except the offending directory.  Add a prefix of `rm -rf` to that line.  Exit editor.  Execute as a shell script: `sh filenames`

Comment: May be better to us `.` instead of `*` as in `ls | egrep "^akorg.$" | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I suppose I didn't make it clear enough earlier, but I'm not actually trying to remove `akorg✽`, just the "invisible" file that's in the way of renaming it.

Comment: Then I wasn't clear either: I don't think you have an "invisible" file. You have a file that has a name with a prefix of "akorg", and a few non-zero-value bytes at the end. Various tools choose to display that filename different ways, giving you the impression that an "invisible" file or directory exists. The only "invisible" things in Unix/Linux have names that begin with a '.', and that's only by convention of the `ls` command.